# can sonar scanner work without sonarqube server to be up and running

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Sonar Scanner analysis work without pushing the results to the SonarQube server?

sonar scanner is giving

```
ERROR: SonarQube server [http://127.0.0.1:9000] can not be reached
[14:15:57]  [Step 2/4] ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
[14:15:57]  [Step 2/4] org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
```

Answer (score 2):

No it can not. The scanner relies on the SonarQube Server to fetch a ruleset to execute this. Additionally it will check if you violate your quality gate or not. The server is your Rule Managament and Decision maker, where as the scanner, is just checking your code based on the rules provided.

The question is, what is your usecase. Do you just want to verify during development, that everything is working accordingly, you could use SonarLint which has a built-in default set, but can be also configured to connect to sonarqube/sonarcloud server to fetch data.

If you do not have the possibility to host your own sonarqube server, you can also take a look at sonarcloud.io - which is a cloud offering from SonarSource and a similar product to sonarqube (similar but not the same). It is free for open source, but also provide paid plans.

Comment: I am integrating sonarscanner with teamcity CI-CD pipeline which is running in Linux. i do not want to I would like to fail my maven build after scan to my java project. if scanner run successfully build should work but if scanner qaulity gate failed my maven build should also fails.